# php-fpm does not access env var

Tags: php, environment-variables, fpm

I want to expose env vars defined in `/etc/environment` to php-fpm.

I turn `clear_env = no` in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` but this as no effect.

I also tried to `source /etc/environment` in `/etc/init.d/php7.3-fpm`: no effect!

How to expose env vars defined in `/etc/environment` to php-fpm without duplicating them manually in `/etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`?